# Problems getting existing symfony2 app up and running locally

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php

I am currently implementing a new feature into an existing webapplication. This webapp has been developed with Symfony2. I have copied the entire webapp from the server using FTP but am now struggling to the app working locally. Every time I try to solve a problem (by looking it up on internet) a new problem emerges.

**Here are the different attempts I have made**

1. **"php app\console server:run"** gives **"proc_open(): CreateProcess
   failed, error code - 267 [...]"**
2. I did **"composer update"** but this gives error **"Failed to execute git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no /n error: bad index file sha1 signature /n fatal: index file corrupt "**. This error occurs for a couple of third party bundles.
3. A search on internet reveals I should use **"rm -f .git/index;git
   reset"**. This does not make a difference when executed in the main project folder. I have also done this in the specific folder of the third party bundle, as these also contain a .git/index. This gives a new error: **'atal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/remotes/origin/master**.

> In the meanwhile - after step 2 - when trying to run the app on the server gives a new type of error:
>
> Fatal Error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle' not found in C:\PATH-TO-APP\app\AppKernel.php on line 16.
>
> **Remark:** This specific bundle has not been a problem while updating with composer (see step 2), and the class can be found in *"vendor\symfony\swiftmailer-bundle\SwiftmailerBundle.php"* and is added in autoload with *"'Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle'),"

I have been cracking my head on every new problem, but I am not getting anywhere here. Am I doing something wrong by copying a project via FTP? I havent gotten any response from the original developer to access the project as a git repository.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some git hooks and scripts to run when you are using `composer.phar update`

You can edit your `composer.json` file to `post`-`load` default scripts instead your specific:

```
"scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
```